# Is there any way to run a setup script for jest testing?

Tags: testing, jestjs

I am looking to run a script that defines constants and functions that is reused many times in my jest tests, is there any way to do that? Such as a setup.spec.js that always runs or define a parameter in the command line such as npm jest -setup etc?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array

Answer (score 6):

There is an option in jest.config.js for this purpose:

```js
// The paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment before each test
  setupFiles: [
    './mySetupScript.js'
  ],
```

jest v24.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Try the beforeAll method. It runs before any test execution. Be aware that to Jest every test file is a new instance and has its own environment, hence, your setup will have to be executed for each test file.